# Stock promotion laws/regulations

Tags: united-states, stocks, etf, mutual-funds, sec

Does the SEC have any guidelines regarding companies promoting the purchase of their shares to hedge funds, pension funds or ETF issuers?

Is it legal for companies to compensate ETF issuers or mutual funds for adding their shares to the fund?

Can companies compensate Index providers such as MSCI or S&P for adding their shares to an Index?

I would appreciate any links or references to SEC materials/regulations (and/or European regulators)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a legal question.

Comment: Yes, there is a legal/regulatory aspect to this question but it primarily pertains to finance. Since there is no SE page that is specifically focused on securities laws, I believe this is the most relevant page to post this.

Comment: @MustardTiger it may be about finance, but it's not about *personal* finance.  Please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Would this information not be relevant to any personal investor who owns ETFs or mutual funds?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I will vote to reopen this as it is the precursor to personal finance questions of how to evaluate disclosures written in financial products, and easily wordable as a personal finance question of basic investing portfolio suitability. The person simply isn't aware of the role of disclosures in SEC regulated financial products

Answer (score 2):

> Is it legal for companies to compensate ETF issuers or mutual funds for adding their shares to the fund?

Where the SEC regulates a potential conflict of interest it is just regarding disclosure. So in the fine print disclaimer, it might mention if a payment occurred for inclusion, and thats it.